# Filling a log table from a pivot in excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Hi guys Im creating a macro with the macro recorder on excel what I want this macro to do is to take the values from a row in a pivot table and paste it in a list that Im using to track the changes of this pivot table values through time like an entry.

the code the recorder gave was the below one

```
Range("U19:Y19").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("E18:I18").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("U20:Y20").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("N18:R18").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

As you can see is a simple copy a range of cells and paste it somewhere else however what I want to happen is that every time I run this macro this list gets filled on the next available row so if I run it the first time it pastes the information in E18:I18 and N18:R18 but if I run it the second time it pastes the information in E19:I19 and N19:R19 and so on and so forth on the subsequent rows each time I run the macro, Im starting with this macro thing and Im still catching up with how to write code

Thanks a lot

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: Ok that will help me to find the last row and then how do I paste the information afterwards? Ill use the one to find last row in a table shall I make a separate macro of this code and then call it on the above?

Comment: figure it out with the below:                                                 
Range("U20:Y20").Copy Range("N515").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: Nice! Looks good.

Comment: No Im running the below code, that sdoes exactly the same from another fields of the pivot to another table, everthing on the same worksheet, the first works, the second doesnt

Comment: my code is this: Sub AiSLogCompletedCR()
' AiSLogCompletedCR
' AiS Status log entry for CR's on Completed Status
    Range("U19:Y19").Copy Range("E515").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
End Sub

Sub AiSLoginflightCR()
' AiSLoginflightCR
' AiS Status log entry for CR's on Completed Status
    Range("U20:Y20").Copy Range("N515").End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0)
End Sub

Comment: If you have a new issue, please ask a new question, thanks!